# Transfer Learning Deep CNN with different resolution

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am reading the paper of [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLO9000.pdf). It mentions that, in page 2 high-resolution classifier,

`The original YOLO trains the classifier network at 224*224 and increases the resolution to 448 for detection.`

`For YOLOv2 we first fine tune the classification network at the full 448*448 resolution for 10 epochs on ImageNet.`

I am just curious how we can do fine-tuning with a different input resolution.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this? Is there any "standard" way to do this?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: I am using Keras and now the solution could be simple: just increase the input size while keeping the filers size as they are. Initialized all the filters and do the fine-tuning. I have achieved improved results on higher res images for my own task.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be just scaling the network to accept input images that are 448x448 resolution, and training for 10 more epochs using the pre-trained weights.

Darknet has resizing capability, so this is easier than it sounds. If you were to do it yourself, you could simply change width=448 and height=448 in the .cfg file and darknet will initialize the layers to accept that resolution.